# How to return some * data with time interval?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a monitoring system. Retrieves the user's location every 5 seconds. However, I want to show only the records that appear in the range and every 15 seconds. Maybe I'll choose a start date and an end date to show these values.... I'm trying to make this filter and I'm not getting it.

I have the following table below:

```
+------------+-------------------+
|     ID     |       date_       |
+------------+-------------------+
|     1      |2017-07-10 10:11:10|
+------------+-------------------+
|     2      |2017-07-10 10:11:15|
+------------+-------------------+
|     3      |2017-07-10 10:11:20|
+------------+-------------------+
|     4      |2017-07-10 10:11:25|
+------------+-------------------+
|     5      |2017-07-10 10:11:30|
+------------+-------------------+
|     6      |2017-07-10 10:11:35|
+------------+-------------------+
|     7      |2017-07-10 10:11:40|
+------------+-------------------+
```

I would like a * query * that returns me only the data of a difference of 15 seconds. For this example above, I would return the following lines:

```
+------------+-------------------+
|     ID     |       date_       |
+------------+-------------------+
|     1      |2017-07-10 10:11:10|
+------------+-------------------+
|     4      |2017-07-10 10:11:25|
+------------+-------------------+
|     7      |2017-07-10 10:11:40|
+------------+-------------------+
```

I want to return only some data by ignoring some rows based on an hour, for example, 15 seconds. This based on the last registered date, for example: `2017-07-10 10:11:40`.

How to return some * data with time interval?

**Obs.:** I'm sorry for English.

Comment: How are you determining when the 15 second window starts?  Based on the information provided, the resultset containing only `2` and `5`, and the resultset of `3` and `6` are perfectly valid as well.  Is this always starting from `ID = 1` or are you specifying a time?

Comment: @Siyual I would like to start with the last recorded date. Example: `2017-07-10 10:11:10`

Comment: The interval is only for the same day hour and minutes? For the case `2017-07-10 10:11:40` if existed an entry with date `2017-07-10 10:12:40` should be output?

Comment: @lucianov88 It is a monitoring system. Retrieves the user's location every 5 seconds. However, I want to show only the records that appear in the range and every 15 seconds. Maybe I'll choose a start date and an end date to show these values.... I'm trying to make this filter and I'm not getting it.

Comment: @acklay, an easy approach would be to calculate the seconds in the interval and see if the seconds belongs to the date, something like this:

`SELECT * FROM `tiempo` WHERE date BETWEEN :begin AND :end AND DATE_FORMAT(date,'%s') IN ('00','15','30','45'); `

Comment: Are the values in the ID field guaranteed to be consecutive?

Comment: @DanBracuk The ID is auto-increment sequential =D

Answer (score 0):

How about a self-join with a timestampdiff()?

```
select t2.*
from yourTable t1 join yourTable t2 on timestampdiff(second t1.date_, t2.date_) =15
```

Since your desired results included the first row, you might want a union query consisting of the above, plus

```
select *
from yourTable
where date_ = (select min(date_ from yourTable)
```

Comment: This only works for the first item. From the second onwards it no longer works.